# PHP/MySQL - How to adjust query based on the length (characters) within database

Tags: php, mysql

I've had excellent support here, so I figured I'd try again, as I have no clue where to even begin looking for this answer.

I have a simple MySQL database, named "testimonials", which contains 3 tables, "id", "name", "content"

What I want to do, is display testimonials within a fixed size block. Just simply displaying the content is no problem at all, however where I'm stuck is the (somewhat) unique way I'm trying to make it work. I would like to display a random item on each page load, and then to check the character length of the "content" within the testimonial, and if it's equal to or greater than XX length, then just display the one testimonial, otherwise if it's less than XX in length to display a second testimonial (assuming it combined with the first doesn't break the container box).

The box in question is 362px in width and 353px in height using 14px font with Verdana. An example of how the testimonial will appear on the page is like this:

*"This is the testimonial content, some nice message from a client."*
**-- Billy Bob, Owner, Crazy Joe's Tavern**

The "name" table in the database holds everything in bold (minus the -- of course), in case someone felt the need to ask.

As I typed that, I felt as if I was asking for a miracle, however I'll still post the question, hoping someone might just know the answer. As always, thanks for any help I may get, if this is just simply asking too much, I'm not totally against the idea of only displaying one testimonial at a time making a ground rule saying they have to contain a minimum of XX characters.

Thanks!

Quick Update: I didn't expect to get answers so quickly, I'm not at my desk at the moment, so as soon as I sit back down I'll go through and see which answer fits best. However, do you guys get together and try to make your answer more complex than the previous answer? lol, thanks though, for anyone who's offering help, you guys rock!

Final edit: I decided against this whole idea, as it just way over complicated everything. For the time being, I'm just going to display all testimonials, and make them scroll, while I work on a jQuery snippet to make it prettier. Thanks everyone for your help though! Should I decide again to do this, I'll be trying my chosen answer.

Comment: You could use [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) with an `if` condition, that could work. Something like `if(strlen($text) > 20) { // show something } else{ // show something else }`

Comment: I'll openly admit I'm not nearly as good with PHP as probably anyone who actually reads this question, but I did consider strlen(), I had actually thought pretty much the same idea as you suggested, with a bunch of if/ifelse statements, but the code I had made looked ridiculous, lol. I also thought about loading every testimonial in an array, but I didn't think that was the right direction to go.

Comment: Have any of the answers below proven to be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a loop. Pseudo-code:

```php
$length = 0;
$target = 200; // or whatever
while( $length < $target ) {
    $comment = getOneComment();
    displayComment($comment);
    $length += strlen( $comment['content'] ); // assuming getOneComment() returns an associative array
}
```

To make it pretty, if the display box is going to a be a fixed height, you could use some jQuery to toggle whether to show the second comment on not.

Comment: I'm obviously not at your level in PHP, but I can follow your logic. Up until the getOneComment(); function, I guess I don't understand where you're going with that to make this work. I know you said it's pseudo-code, but I'm not quite skilled enough with PHP to completely follow you, to try to implement this.

Comment: All I'm saying is to keep track of how long the first comment was.  If it passes a certain threshold (which I called `$target` above and arbitrarily gave a value of 200), then don't display another comment.  If it doesn't, then display another comment. You could also do the check before the display.  For example, maybe you want `$target` to be 200, and it turns out the first two comments are 120 and 100. Then, you wouldn't want to display the second.  You can do this by putting the `$length` update first, then adding a `break` command if `$length > $target`

Comment: Oh, that makes much more sense to me, thank you! It's looking like I wont be able to get back to my desk until tomorrow morning, but I do thank you very much for taking the time to explain this to me!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you would need.

```
<?php
$str = $res["testimonial"];
if (strlen($str) > 50) {
    // Logic to retrieve and display second testimonial
}
?>
```

Obviously there's some more processing you'll have to come up with to determine if the second testimonial is short enough to fit or not. But that should get you started.

EDIT:
For the randomization, I use this on my own site:

```
$referrals = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ts_testimonials");
$referralView = array();
$i = 0;
while ($newReferral = mysql_fetch_array($referrals)) {
  $referralView[$i] = $newReferral['id'];
  $i++;
}
if (sizeof($referralView) >= 1){
  $referralTop = rand(0,sizeof($referralView)-1);
  $newReferralTop = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ts_testimonials WHERE id = '".$referralView[$referralTop]."'"));
  if (sizeof($referralView) >=2){
    $referralBottom = rand(0,sizeof($referralView)-1);
    while ($referralBottom == $referralTop) {
      $referralBottom = rand(0,sizeof($referralView)-1);
    }
    $newReferralBottom = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ts_testimonials WHERE id = '".$referralView[$referralBottom]."'"));
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I follow you here, basically use strlen() to check the length of the initial testimonial displayed, and if it's less than XX display a second, if it's more or equal to XX, don't display a second.

The main part where I'd get snagged is the randomization, like how to randomly choose a testimonial, but if it's too long to choose another, excluding the first one.... The more I think of this the more I'm starting to think it's not the best of ideas..

Comment: The answer provided by Cristian Bitoi looks promising, but my children decided I don't get to sit down again tonight. I'll try every solution to the best of my ability and see which works best.

Comment: @ProtocolZero I edited to help explain some of the randomization options. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have testimonials in an array:

```
$testimonials = array(
     't1' => array(
         'content' => 'testimonials 1 content..',
         'author' => 'the author'
     ),
     't2' => array(
         'content' => 'testimonials 2 content..',
         'author' => 'the author 2'
     ),
);
```

You could have an `maxLengthTestimonialsContent` and `maxLenthAllTestimonnials` variable :

```
$maxLengthTestimonialsContent = 120;
$maxLenthAllTestimonnials = 240;
```

And now with a simple loop you build the array testimonials that you will use to show:

```
$testimonialsToShow = array();

$i = 1; $totalLength = 0
foreach($testimonials as $t) {
    if( $i > 1 && strlen( $t['content']) < $maxLengthTestimonialsContent
        &&  $totalLength < $maxLenthAllTestimonnials  )
        break; // basically here you test that testimonials less first
               // and with less length than maxLengthTestimonial, and also
               // total length less than maxLengthAll to be stored 
               //in $testimonialsToShow

    else {
        $testimonialsToShow[] = $t;
        $totalLength = $t['content'];
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite the answer you provided, I'll give it a shot when I can get back to my desk.